# How to set value of a variable in C++ when it's not in global scope and used in custom function?

Tags: c++

The variables are not accepting the values I'm entering in my C++ program. I must avoid global variables and use only local variables. And the function returns nothing, so I have used "void" instead of "int" type. Same thing happening when I use strings or any type of custom function. Here is the example to explain my problem:

```
#include <iostream>


void sum (int a, int b, int c);

int main (void)
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;

    sum (a, b, c);

    std::cout << a << b << c;

    return 0;
}


void sum (int a, int b, int c) // It doesn't have to be the same variable name :)
{
    std::cout << "Enter value of a:\n";
    std::cin  >> a;
    std::cout << "Enter value of b:\n";
    std::cin  >> b;
    std::cout << "Enter value of c:\n";
    std::cin  >> c;

    a = b+c;
}
```

Comment: You want to have reference parameters for the results: `void sum (int& a, int& b, int& c);`

Comment: I'm assuming this was just for an example, but if you really want to have an int changed like that you should return the result rather than pass it in as a reference.

Comment: @GabeSechan yes, this is just an example :)

Comment: Why is the user entering the value of `a` if the function is going to overwrite it with `b+c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pass by reference (or by pointer, for the educational purpose):

```
void sum (int& a, int& b, int& c);
void sum (int* a, int* b, int* c);

int main (void)
{
   int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
   sum (a, b, c);
   std::cout << a << b << c;

   a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
   sum (&a, &b, &c);
   std::cout << a << b << c;

   return 0;
}


void sum (int& a, int& b, int& c)
{
   std::cout << "Enter value of a:\n";
   std::cin  >> a;
   std::cout << "Enter value of b:\n";
   std::cin  >> b;
   std::cout << "Enter value of c:\n";
   std::cin  >> c;
   a = b+c;
}

void sum (int* a, int* b, int* c)
{
   std::cout << "Enter value of a:\n";
   std::cin  >> *a;
   std::cout << "Enter value of b:\n";
   std::cin  >> *b;
   std::cout << "Enter value of c:\n";
   std::cin  >> *c;
   *a = *b + *c;
}
```

Comment: what is the correct syntax? (int &a, int &b, int &c) or (int& a, int& b, int& c)? And thanks for the extra method.

Comment: it is not about syntax in this case, it is only about your code style. I prefer point, that variable "a" has "int reference" type by using "int& a" notation.

Comment: -1 for "or by pointer, for the educational purpose". That's like teaching him how to use a global `void*` instead of the parameters, `memset`ting them in `main` and using a C-style cast in `sum` to retrieve them, all for "the educational purpose"...

Comment: @Christian Hackl, i think you are too aggresive... but it's your choice. I see no any danger in knowing, how to use a pointers.

Comment: @ars: Teaching pointers is OK *if* you mention dangers, problems, differences in idiomatic use between C and C++ etc.; otherwise it's just spreading dangerous half-knowledge. The OP, being a complete beginner in C++, may go on and use them in situations like this because "I've seen it as an alternative on SO". It's like teaching skiing without teaching how to stop.

Comment: @ChristianHackl is it a bad practice to use pointers to pass arguments? if you provide me some articles or information about this, I'll really appreciate it. The problem is, I don't know what to search! Just after reading some answers I realised that I should have searched about "passing arguments by reference" and "Passing arguments by address". I wish English was my first language.

Comment: @Amession: it is bad practice when a reference would do the job. I'll give you some references later when I'm back home.

Comment: @Amession: here we go, I guess you should first read the C++ FAQ at https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#refs-vs-ptrs. Pointers can do many more things, not just refer to one other object. This is the problem; you mostly don't need these other things. For just one example, pointers can be made to refer to nothing, which means that your code gets full of `!= 0` (or `!= nullptr` in C++11) checks to avoid illegal dereferencing which would cause undefined behaviour (resulting e.g. in crashes). References always refer to exactly one other object and cannot be "nothing".

Answer (score 8):

[Pass by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/):

```
void sum (int &a, int &b, int &c)
```

Comment: Only a needs to be a reference here.

Comment: @GabeSechan well he prints b and c in main after the call so I suppose he wants those to be references also

Comment: Thank you! it solved my problem, I haven't seen "&" much in C++ programming, I'm noob.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments can be passed by value or by reference to a function.
When you pass an argument by a value (which is what you are doing), a separate copy is created of the variable and is stored in a different memory location.
When you pass by reference (using a pointer), same memory location is referenced. Basically in your code you are creating a separate copy of the variable referenced by the same name and modifying that copy and expecting the changes in the original. The solution is to use pointers.