# Map doesn't store values in recursion

Tags: c++, dictionary, recursion

I do not know why but when recursion tries to add value and then to return it that map after return of function deletes all elements, I do not understand in what a problem.

```
static int SumNum(string target, string m[], map<string, int> memo = {}){

        if (memo.find(target) != memo.end()) {
            cout << memo.find(target)->second<<"\n";
            return memo.find(target)->second;
        }
        if (target == "") return 1;

        int totalCount = 0;
        
    for(auto i = 0;i < 10; i++)
    {   
        if (target.find(m[i]) == 0){
            
            int numOfWays = SumNum(target.substr(m[i].length()),m,memo);
            totalCount += numOfWays;
            
        }
    }
    memo.emplace(target, totalCount);
    return totalCount;
}
int main(){
    string ar[10] = {"e","ee","eee","eeee","eeeee","eeeeee","f","fdc","d","c"};
    string target = "eeeeeeeeefdc";
    auto answer = SumNum(target,ar);
    cout << answer;
}
```

Comment: probably pass the map by reference ?

Comment: Do you know the difference between passing parameters by value versus by reference?

Comment: @Max No,how to do it in my code?

Comment: references are a basic and fundamental concept in C++. You should read a good C++ book [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: thx,i'll read that but  i need solution now

Comment: @skamer *"but i need solution it now"* -- your emergency is not our emergency. Please see [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and be aware that the primary purpose of SO is to provide a resource for *future* visitors. It's just a pleasant side-effect when the person asking the question also benefits.

Comment: yeah,you right,sorry,i'll wait for solution so far

Comment: @skamer people already told you how to do it, just pass the map by reference, instead of by value. SO is not a place for people to write the code for you, is for them to help you know the answers to problems you tried alone and wasn't able to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set value of a variable in C++ when it's not in global scope and used in custom function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338167/how-to-set-value-of-a-variable-in-c-when-its-not-in-global-scope-and-used-in)

Answer (score 0):

I think that @Max meant this:

```cpp
static int SumNum(std::string target, std::string m[], std::map<std::string, int>& memo /* pass by reference */){

        if (memo.find(target) != memo.end()) {
            std::cout << memo.find(target)->second<<"\n";
            return memo.find(target)->second;
        }
        if (target == "") return 1;

        int totalCount = 0;
        
    for(auto i = 0;i < 10; i++)
    {   
        if (target.find(m[i]) == 0){
            
            int numOfWays = SumNum(target.substr(m[i].length()),m,memo);
            totalCount += numOfWays;
            
        }
    }
    memo.emplace(target, totalCount);
    return totalCount;
}
int main(){
    std::map <std::string, int> map;
    std::string ar[10] = {"e","ee","eee","eeee","eeeee","eeeeee","f","fdc","d","c"};
    std::string target = "eeeeeeeeefdc";
    auto answer = SumNum(target, ar, map);
    std::cout << answer;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work , you need to initialize map,compilator is said it

Comment: @skamer I have edited my code.

Answer (score -3):

thanks @Max i did like you say

```
static int SumNum(string target, string m[], map<string, int> *memo = new map<string, int>()) {
        
        if (memo->find(target) != memo->end()) {
            cout << memo->find(target)->second<<"\n";
            return memo->find(target)->second;
        }
        if (target == "") return 1;

        int totalCount = 0;
        
    for(auto i = 0;i < 10; i++)
    {   
        if (target.find(m[i]) == 0){
            
            int numOfWays = SumNum(target.substr(m[i].length()),m,memo);
            totalCount += numOfWays;
            
        }
    }
    memo->emplace(target, totalCount);
    return totalCount;
}
int main(){
    string ar[10] = {"e","ee","eee","eeee","eeeee","eeeeee","f","fdc","d","c"};
    string target = "eeeeeeeeeeeeefdc";
    auto answer = SumNum(target,ar);
    cout << answer;
}
```

Comment: Your code leaks memory (and does not do what Max suggested). When you use the default parameter, a map is created with `new` but never `delete`d. The suggestion was to use a reference, not to use a pointer. (Using a pointer would be the C way to "pass by reference", but you are using C++. C++ uses references.)

Comment: @skamer Please run the code with `valgrind` and fix the errors it will point out. (It will give you the exact line numbers and useful memory management hints with a `-g`-compiled binary.) What you have in the answer looks like a memory management disaster.

Comment: i see you are from Poland ,can we contact ?

Comment: it is disaster but i am only beginning to studying

Comment: ==8896== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8896==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8896==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8896==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8896==    still reachable: 1,766 bytes in 55 blocks
==8896==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8896== 
==8896== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Comment: is that ok test?